# Setting up Yeoman-- multiple bower_components

Tags: javascript, yeoman, bower

First time setting up a Yeoman app.  I think I understand how bower works... but my app seems to be having trouble finding jquery.js (and perhaps other libraries).

The console message is

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) [localhost]/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js**

which seems pretty straightforward... it's not linking up properly (duh).  I went back into the directory structure of my app, and it looks like there are two `/bower_components/` folders.

One of the folders (the one outside of the `/app/` directory) only has a jquery folder.  The other one (inside the `/app/` directory) has all of my libraries and goodies (coffee-script, jquery, ember, etc...).

**First:**  Are there supposed to be two `/bower_components/` folders (one for production and one for local perhaps)?

**Second:**  How can I get my app to grab the `js` from the correct folder?

### EDIT:

Please unmark as duplicate.  I already saw that question.  My `.bowerrc` file is pointing to the correct directory.

```
{
    "directory": "app/bower_components"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a global `.bowerrc`. Check for one in `~/`, which specifies:

```
{
    "directory": "bower_components"
}
```

Get rid of that file and see if it helps!